# Turn off anti-aliasing on svg when applying CSS3:Zoom on the element?

Tags: css, svg, antialiasing

I found that when the CSS3 Zoom is applied on small SVG icons (9px:9px with zoom: 1.5), the SVG icons could be blurry. Any idea to get a sharp and clean icon in this case? Thanks in advance.

The SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve"
         x="0px" y="0px" width="9px" height="9px" viewBox="0 0 9 9" enable-background="new 0 0 9 9">
    <g>
        <g fill="none" transform="translate(0.5, 0.5)"> 
            <g stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" stroke-linecap="square" >
                <line x1="2" y1="4"  x2="6" y2="4"/>
                <line x1="4"  y1="2" x2="4" y2="6"/>
            </g>
            <g stroke="#909090" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" >
                <rect x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Which browser? Some browsers don't recalculate the SVG when resizing or zooming. What is CSS3 Zoom? Do you mean just zooming in with the browser? Or the non-standard IE property?

Comment: Thanks for your notice of my question. Here is some information of the [CSS3 Zoom](http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/). It is widely supported by most modern browsers. I'm trying this on Chrome and Safari iOS.

Comment: Yes, this is non-standard. It is likely just zooming the rendered element without recalculating. Have you tried using the scale transform function instead? Or maying the original SVG larger and scaling down when initially displaying it?

Comment: Well I got a solution myself. Add: shape-rendering="crispEdges" to the svg will do the trick. Thanks @DavidStorey.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Got a solution myself. The trick is adding:

```
shape-rendering="crispEdges"
```

to the SVG elements.

From [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering):

> **crispEdges**
>   Indicates that the user agent shall attempt to emphasize the contrast between clean edges of artwork over rendering speed and geometric precision. To achieve crisp edges, **the user agent might turn off anti-aliasing** for all lines and curves or possibly just for straight lines which are close to vertical or horizontal. Also, the user agent might adjust line positions and line widths to align edges with device pixels.

See the difference on [jsFilddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RGBxP/).

Comment: Anyone know the browser support on this? Can't seem to find any reference to it.

Comment: As of 2016, browser support can be found here http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-crisp-edges

Comment: As promising as it sounds, the support for `crispEdges` in Sept 2017 is still limited to Firefox and Safari and the result looks in Firefox sub-optimally more like `pixelated` than anything else: https://codepen.io/Volker_E/pen/wrBJYb

Comment: Maybe it's different now @VolkerE. but Firefox and Chrome render that CodePen identically for me (can't check Safari rn).

Comment: @Luciano, this caniuse link stands for `image-rendering` property, which is a different things.